# save 2 array fields as new array?

Tags: php, arrays

My problem may seem very simple, and I'm probably missing something. I need to save 2 fields from an array called `$data1` as a different array.

```
[cat_id] => 1
[parent_id] => 0
[cat_left] => 1
[options] => 0
[name] => soccer
[creator] => 0
```

and I need to save `cat_id => name`, like :

```
1 => soccer
```

I tried with foreach but all I managed to do is mess up more.

```
foreach($data1 as $k=>$v)
        {
            $cat_arr[]= $v['cat_id'] => $v['name'];
        }
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume, that `$data1` holds multiple sub-arrays of the form you posted. Then you can just use code like this:

```
$cat_arr = array();
foreach($data1 as $k=>$v) {
  $cat_arr[ $v['cat_id'] ]= $v['name'];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`array_map()`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-map.php), which is more elegant:

```
$data2 = array_map(
    function ($n) {
        return array($n['cat_id'] => $n['name']);
    },
    $data1
);
```

[Fiddle](http://phpfiddle.org/main/code/eyb-tna)